# Calculating standard deviation (Python)

Tags: python, errorbar

I calculated the mean of every nth element from 4 lists like in this example below. I would like to caluculate the standard deviation from that and add it as error bars to my plot

```
y1 = [1, 2, 2, 4, 5]
y2 = [3, 6, 9, 12, 0]
y3 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y4 = [2, 1, 5, 7, 9]

average = np.array([y1, y2, y3, y4]).mean(axis=0)
y = average.tolist()

plot(x,y)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

To address your first question, you can calculate the standard deviation in much the same way as you are currently calculating the average. [Numpy has a `std` function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) which takes similar arguments to `mean`.

```
std_dev = np.array([y1, y2, y3, y4]).std(axis=0)
```

For the second question, assuming that `plot(x,y)` is from `matplotlib.pyplot`, [you could instead use `errorbar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html), which takes an extra `yerr` argument which lets you specify your error bars.

A full example script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
y1 = [1, 2, 2, 4, 5]
y2 = [3, 6, 9, 12, 0]
y3 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y4 = [2, 1, 5, 7, 9]

datasets = np.array([y1, y2, y3, y4])
average = datasets.mean(axis=0)
std_dev = datasets.std(axis=0)

plt.errorbar(x, average, yerr=std_dev)
plt.show()
```